# How do I attach multiple GIFs and adjust the FPS?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I want to attach several GIFs and then change the FPS to 10.
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 1.txt -filter:v fps=fps=1 -c copy output.gif`

Executing the above command will result in the following error:

`Filtergraph 'fps=fps=10' was defined for video output stream 0:0 but codec copy was selected.
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.`

Except for filter options to adjust the FPS, the following error will not occur, but another problem will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-c copy` because you can't [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) and filter the same stream at the same time.

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 1.txt -filter:v fps=10 output.gif
```